# Type.GetProperties() missing in Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

In Xamarin PCL, I'm trying to get the System.Reflection.PropertyInfo of a class I've written so that I can access its properties by their string name to get/set, and Type.GetTypeInfo() is missing, as well as Type.GetProperties. But System.Reflection.PropertyInfo is a valid class. How can I obtain the property info of a class? Do I have to write a wrapper for each platform? (It shows up just fine in the Android/iOS projects).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have just run into this, pretty sure the answer is to use:

```
Type.GetRuntimeProperties
```

Comment: More relevant information on a similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05eebec9-b56f-4b55-9624-dabfc6d24bbd/typeisassignablefrom-in-portable-class-library

Answer (score 32):

It's an extension, so you need to put

```
using System.Reflection;
```

at the top. Then it's available:

```
        TypeInfo typeInfo = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in typeInfo.DeclaredProperties)
```

Comment: Just tried this in Profile78. It's still not available.

Comment: It doesn't work because `GetProperties()` is excluded from the PCL subset. Although this should indeed enable `GetTypeInfo()`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how I was able to access the object properties by adding using System.Reflection;

Comment: Maybe that does solve the problem in your particular case, but the `DeclaredProperties` is not a sibstitute for `GetProperties()`. It's because `DeclaredProperties` does not include inherited properties.

Comment: How do I filter to public properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
using System.Reflection; 

Type t = typeof(YOURTYPE);
var properties = t.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties
```