# Verify existence of non-public property by name in Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, system.reflection

Question:

In a Xamarin PCL project, is there any way to verify that a property with a given name exists, for a property that is **not** public?

---

Context:

In my `ViewModelBase` class, the `OnPropertyChanged` calls a debug-only method. It helps me finding wrong arguments for OnPropertyChanged in case I could not use the `CallerMemberName` logic and had to pass an explicit value for `propertyName`:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  // ...

  protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    // More code that is the reason why calling OnPropertyChanged can
    // make sense even for private or protected properties in my code.
  }

  [Conditional("DEBUG"), DebuggerStepThrough]
  private void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
  {
    // This only finds public properties
    if (GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(propertyName) == null) {
      // TODO
      // Check if there is a non-public property
      // If there is, only print a hint
      throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name: " + propertyName);
    }
  }

  // ...

}
```

The problem is that `GetRuntimeProperty` only finds public properties, i. e. calling `OnPropertyChanged` for a private property triggers that exception.

I would like to weaken the condition so that calling `OnPropertyChanged` for non-public properties only triggers a `Debug.Print`, because my `ViewModelBase.OnPropertyChanged` contains more code so that calling `OnPropertyChanged` *can* become beneficial for private or protected properties.

But neither the `System.Type` object obtained by `GetType()` nor `System.Reflection.TypeInfo` obtained through `GetType().GetTypeInfo()` as mentioned [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26909994/1843468) seem to have methods to find anything else but *public* properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer, as per [Furkan Fidan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718974/verify-existence-of-non-public-property-by-name-in-xamarin-pcl/41719874#comment70637355_41719874):

[`GetRuntimeProperty`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperty/p/System.Type/System.String/) only finds public properties, so it returns `null` if the given property is not public.

However you can retrieve a list of all properties (including the non-public ones) by calling the [`GetRuntimeProperties`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties/p/System.Type/) method. You can then filter the result using LINQ.

```
private void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
{
  if (GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(propertyName) != null) {
    // The property is public
  } else if (GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Any(p => p.Name == propertyName)) {
    // The property is not public, but it exists
  } else {
    // The property does not exist
  }
}
```

See also the remarks of `GetRuntimeProperties`:

> This method returns all properties defined on the specified type, including inherited, non-public, instance, and static properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the private fields of a type by passing the non public [binding flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) to [GetFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx) method. See a quick and dirty example below.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class MyClass
{
    private int privField;

    public MyClass(int val)
    {
        this.privField = val;
    }

    public void printValueOfPrivate()
    {
        var fields = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + fields[0].Name + " Value: " + fields[0].GetValue(this));
    }
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        var mc = new MyClass(7);
        mc.printValueOfPrivate();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: privField Value: 7
```

**Edit:**

See comments for details but basically to achieve what @LWChris wants you need to call GetRuntimeProperties() on GetType() as GetRuntimeProperty() doesn't return private properties.

Comment: Sorry my bad - I've only tried with mono on the MacOS. Looking a bit deeper, you're right GetFields is not supported on PCL but instead GetRuntimeFields & GetRuntimeProperties need to be used. [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions.getruntimeproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) remarks that it should include non-private as well. What's the documentation you are looking?

Comment: The "documentation" is that I get an exception when I run my code that uses `if (GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(propertyName) == null) throw ...`.

Comment: And `GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(string propertyName)` has a documentation that is "Returns an object that represents the specified **public** property declared by the current type".

Comment: Documentation for GetRuntimeProperty doesn't say anything about it retrieving non-public fields. I know it may not be efficient but for the sake of science can you try calling GetRuntimeProperties and enumerating through them to see if the property you're looking for is there?

Comment: Hah, you're right! `GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(propertyName)` returns null, but `GetType().GetRuntimeProperties()` returns an array that actually contains an element for the property. Edit your answer to contain this information and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad  to hear it worked - we both learned something! I'll update the answer for future reference.

Comment: We should adapt the provided code example rather than adding an "Edit"-section that states "forget the above, this is the actual solution". I'll update the answer later this evening and then accept it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to improve your answer and give the credit to you by accepting your answer, but my edit was rejected because it obviously changed the whole code. So I had to post the suggested edit as answer myself and accept that, because that's the right way for PCL.

Comment: No worries - thanks for taking the time to share it!!