# get properties through a string object with c # - Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, object, reflection, xamarin.forms, equals

I have an object of 500 properties, my need is to call the object dynamically using string. How can I do using c #?

```
public class MyObjects
    {    
    public int RGP_Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime RGP_DateTime { get; set; }
    public int RGP_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_1 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_2 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_3 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_4 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_5 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_6 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_7 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_8 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_9 { get; set; }
    public int RGP_IDREG_10 { get; set; }
    .......
    public int RGP_IDREG_500 { get; set; }

}
```

I would need to call the object's properties and return its value, using string.

target example:

```
var x = MyObjects.GetPropertyValue("RGP_IDREG_10");
```

it's possible ?

Comment: The demonstrated goal isn't really clear to me.  You want a `static` method called `Equals()` which takes a `string` and does what exactly?  What would `x` be after this operation?

Comment: I would need to call the object's properties and return its value, through the string ...

Comment: it's not a duplicate @David this is for xamarin forms....GetProperty() not exist in xamarin forms c#

Comment: Interesting.  Can you elaborate on how you've attempted to use that solution and in what way it failed?

Comment: I am trying with the GetType () but does not have methods that can retrieve a value by string, the reflection I can not use it because the .net xaamrin forms does not support this feature fully.

Comment: @Mr. Developer Did you think about using a `List` instead of 500 properties?

Comment: Yes I thought about list, but this project is shared project and I can't change the object..

Comment: getting the property will require reflection, and reflection can be slow, esp. on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909316/type-getproperties-missing-in-xamarin-pcl) to get the property list and then access the property. You will need to use System.Reflection but it should be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using anything else than this, because it require reflection, and reflection might be slow, but if you really want to do it...

```cs
using System.Reflection;

...

var objects = new MyObjects();
var propertyInfo = typeof(MyObjects).GetRuntimeProperty("RGP_IDREG_1");
var value = (int)(propertyInfo.GetMethod.Invoke(objects, new object [] {}));
```

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION in Xamarin Forms**

```
var profile = MyObjects;
var idProperty = GetProperty(profile.GetType().GetTypeInfo(), "RGP_IDREG_10");
var x = idProperty.GetValue(profile, null);
```

idProperty contain value from property

Comment: provided that `GetProperty` does what I think it does and you either mixed up the way to invoke an extension method, it doesn't returns a value, but a `PropertyInfo`

Comment: sorry, i've got correction, i'm forgot add GetValue. now works.